# Unresolved constraint in bundle - osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.asm.tree)

Tags: spring, tree, java-bytecode-asm

I'm getting below exception. Using karaf 3.0.1 container. There is no jar or package -org.springframework.asm.tree. but it is complaining as missing requirement. Please suggest.

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle  myapp [80]: Unable to resolve 80.1: missing requirement [80.1] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.asm.tree)

Thanks